# Restore .backup file of postgreSql in MySql server

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Is there any simple way to import .backup files of postgreSql database to MySql database to create a Spatial database.

Comment: No, most PostGIS functions, datatypes and operators don't exist in MySQL.

Comment: @FrankHeikens thanks for your help ... but please help me out to sort out this problem, as I am in mid of my project ...

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't just restore a PostgreSQL dump to MySQL, or vice versa.

Research migration from PostgreSQL to MySQL. There are a few answers on this topic here on Stack Overflow and on dba.stackexchange.com.

SQL is one of those "standards" that's rather more honoured in the breach than in the observance. The basics are shared, but once you get to DDL, dumps and backups, index definitions, functions, etc standards rapidly go out the window.

Comment: is there no way to do this ??

Comment: Sure. Restore to a PostgreSQL instance, then use one of the existing techniques to migrate the data and schema over to MySQL. No, there is no way to restore a PostgreSQL backup directly to MySQL.